# FosUserBundle create new group

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using FOSUserBundle with Symfony3 to develop my admin backend. When I try to add a group, I've got this error:

> Exception detected!  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT
>   t0.name AS name_1, t0.roles AS roles_2, t0.id AS id_3 FROM group t0
>   WHERE t0.name = ?' with params ["TEST"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group t0
>   WHERE t0.name = 'TEST'' at line 1 500 Internal Server Error -
>   SyntaxErrorException 2 linked Exceptions: PDOException » PDOException
>   »

Comment: You should ask questions in English, not French.

Comment: Have you persist your model in MariaDB ? Have you a good db_driver on symfony config for mariaDB ?